# A way to get the path to the user installed packages on Linux and OS X operating systems? (Usable for Python versions between 2.5 - 2.7)

Tags: python, linux, macos, path, python-2.x

```
>>> import distutils.sysconfig
>>> distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

But I want this path: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.
I can't use the `sysconfig` module because it is only supported on python2.7 and there is no PyPI download to that module. so I could not even use a requirements file to let other users download it with pip.

So, is there any way to get the path to my installed packages that works for Linux and OS X operating systems? (or even all Unix based os's)

Comment: You want the base directory where installed packages go, the directory of each package?

Comment: Yes, the base directory where installed packages go. For `CentOS 5.6` for example this would be `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` while on `Ubuntu 11.04` it would be `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the specific functionality of the `get_python_lib` function, the [source for that module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2370e331241b/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py) is fairly straightforward and doesn't use any Python 2.7 specific syntax at all; you could simply backport it.

You'd basically need the following definitions and two functions:

```
import os
import sys
from distutils.errors import DistutilsPlatformError


PREFIX = os.path.normpath(sys.prefix)
EXEC_PREFIX = os.path.normpath(sys.exec_prefix)


def get_python_version():
    """Return a string containing the major and minor Python version,
    leaving off the patchlevel.  Sample return values could be '1.5'
    or '2.2'.
    """
    return sys.version[:3]

def get_python_lib(plat_specific=0, standard_lib=0, prefix=None):
    """Return the directory containing the Python library (standard or
    site additions).

    If 'plat_specific' is true, return the directory containing
    platform-specific modules, i.e. any module from a non-pure-Python
    module distribution; otherwise, return the platform-shared library
    directory.  If 'standard_lib' is true, return the directory
    containing standard Python library modules; otherwise, return the
    directory for site-specific modules.

    If 'prefix' is supplied, use it instead of sys.prefix or
    sys.exec_prefix -- i.e., ignore 'plat_specific'.
    """
    if prefix is None:
        prefix = plat_specific and EXEC_PREFIX or PREFIX

    if os.name == "posix":
        libpython = os.path.join(prefix,
                                 "lib", "python" + get_python_version())
        if standard_lib:
            return libpython
        else:
            return os.path.join(libpython, "site-packages")

    elif os.name == "nt":
        if standard_lib:
            return os.path.join(prefix, "Lib")
        else:
            if get_python_version() < "2.2":
                return prefix
            else:
                return os.path.join(prefix, "Lib", "site-packages")

    elif os.name == "os2":
        if standard_lib:
            return os.path.join(prefix, "Lib")
        else:
            return os.path.join(prefix, "Lib", "site-packages")

    else:
        raise DistutilsPlatformError(
            "I don't know where Python installs its library "
            "on platform '%s'" % os.name)
```

You can cut the long function down to just the branch you need for your platform, of course; for OS X that'd be:

```
def get_python_lib(plat_specific=0, standard_lib=0, prefix=None):
    if prefix is None:
        prefix = plat_specific and EXEC_PREFIX or PREFIX

    libpython = os.path.join(prefix,
                             "lib", "python" + get_python_version())
    if standard_lib:
        return libpython
    else:
        return os.path.join(libpython, "site-packages")
```

Note that Debian [patches this function](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.3-4.diff.gz) to return `dist-packages` in the default case, this doesn't apply to OS X.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the path, you can use sys.path:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If you want to configure this, you can set the environment variable PYTHON_PATH:

```
export PYTHON_PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

You can also extend it in python if you want to add to it dynamically without changing PYTHON_PATH:

```
import sys
sys.path.extend(['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages'])
```

Comment: The path I need is not `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` on each Linux distribution. I don't understand how your proposed solution could be an answer to my question.